# Flash to mobile compatible video with variable data

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, variables, video

Looking for a solution to convert Flash video on-the-fly to mobile accessible video? Purpose being, I'm creating Flash videos that contain variable data by means of ActionScript... I'm looking for a solution that will convert the swfs to mobile accessible video on demand/in-real time, thereby maintaining the variable data within the video. Is this possible?

Comment: What are the variables in the video?  Because "creating" a video is so much cpu, storage, data, etc., it's a terrible solution - inefficient, costly.

Comment: The variables might be copy fields with user names, phone numbers, addresses, etc... all data input by a csv file and called by the ActionScript. The video itself does not change. I know it's possible, just don't not sure how it's converted for mobile..

Comment: Whenever you say "video" here, it means an external video file.  You're talking about laying text or graphics over the video?  You can store the data in the code or in xml files.  The xml files can be packaged with your app.